# routing table set up with multiple interfaces

Tags: routing, ipv4

I have been able to set up routing table for a simple one without internet access. However I am not able to set it up correctly with multiple interfaces. My set up look like this.

```
#PC1
 address 10.1.10.103
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 broadcast 10.1.10.255
 gateway 10.1.10.10
 network 10.1.10.0

#PC2
 address 192.168.10.10
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 broadcast 192.168.10.255
 network 192.168.10.0
 gateway 192.168.10.2  

#Router

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static 

address 10.1.10.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.1.10.255
network 10.1.10.0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static 

 address 192.168.10.2
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 broadcast 192.168.10.255
 network 192.168.10.0
 gateway 192.168.10.1 

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

pc1 can ping pc2 and vice versa, but pc1 cannot ping 192.168.10.1 !! I don't gate why.
Router has access to the internet but pc1 don't have access to internet.

I have made 192.168.10.1 the default gateway in the routing table but nothing changed. I have also 192.168.10.2 default gateway, it still did not work.

What could be wrong? How do I get pc1 to ping 192.168.10.1 and access the internet? I guess the routing table is wrong

Comment: What is the router model and configuration? The router itself should be the gateway, and it should use a default route, not a different gateway.

Comment: Do you have routing enabled?

Comment: The router is just a computer with ubuntu 12.04 on it.  Yes the router is the gateway. 192.168.10.2 and 10.1.10.10 are addresses of the router

Comment: @RonTrunk is that different from enabling ip_forwarding? if not. I have ip fowarding enabled. that is why actually pc1 can ping pc2

Comment: What device is 192.168.10.1? It doesn't have a route to 10.1.10.0

Comment: @RonTrunk 192.168.10.1 is another computer with ubuntu 16.04 which is also a router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router at 192.168.10.1 doesn't have a route to 10.1.10.0.  You need to add a static route for 10.1.10.0/24 on that device with the next hop at 192.168.10.2

Comment: That was alright I did an alternative, by just masquerading outgoing traffic from the router to  192.168.10.1